# Gzipping Har Files on HDFS using Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, compression, hdfs

I have huge data in hadoop archive `.har` format. Since, `har` doesn't include any compression, I am trying to further gzip it in and store in HDFS. The only thing I can get to work without error is :

```
harFile.coalesce(1, "true")
.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://namenode/archive/GzipOutput", classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec])
//`coalesce` because Gzip isn't splittable.
```

But, this doesn't give me the correct results. A Gzipped file is generated but with invalid output ( a single line saying the rdd type etc.)

Any help will be appreciated. I am also open to any other approaches.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of content do you have in the HAR archives -- CSV, JSON, unstructured text (e.g. logs), binary? Did you consider un-archiving each HAR, GZipping each file inside, and re-archiving? If not binary, did you consider merging the content of each HAR (or multiple HAR) into a single GZipped (or BZipped) file, with a MR or Spark job? If structured, did you consider merging the content of each HAR (or multiple HAR) into columnar format, such as Parquet ou ORC, with GZip compression?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter The har will contain flat text files or parquet files. Nothing like xmls but I don't want the data to split. Gzipping each file is a problem because the har might contain 350+ directories and inside each directory there will be a file. I'm not sure how to do that. I tried compressing that single har file using GZip Compression using PIG. It did succeed in compressing but created part files which would again be undesirable since GZip is not splittable.. Lastly, can't merge multiple HARs because each har needs to be gzipped seperately.

Answer (score 1):

A Java code snippet to create a compressed version of an existing HDFS file.

Built in a hurry, in a text editor, from bits and pieces of a Java app I wrote some time ago, hence not tested; some typos and gaps to be expected.

```
// HDFS API
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
// native Hadoop compression libraries
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Compressor;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec;

..............

  // Hadoop "Configuration" (and its derivatives for  HDFS, HBase etc.) constructors try to auto-magically
  //  find their config files by searching CLASSPATH for directories, and searching each dir for hard-coded  
  //  name "core-site.xml", plus "hdfs-site.xml" and/or "hbase-site.xml" etc.
  // WARNING - if these config files are not found, the "Configuration" reverts to hard-coded defaults without
  //  any warning, resulting in bizarre error messages later > let's run some explicit controls here
  Configuration cnfHadoop = new Configuration() ;
  String propDefaultFs =cnfHadoop.get("fs.defaultFS") ;
  if (propDefaultFs ==null || ! propDefaultFs.startsWith("hdfs://"))
  { throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "HDFS configuration is missing - no proper \"core-site.xml\" found, please add\n"
               +"directory /etc/hadoop/conf/ (or custom dir with custom XML conf files) in CLASSPATH"
               ) ;
  }
/*
  // for a Kerberised cluster, either you already have a valid TGT in the default
  //  ticket cache (via "kinit"), or you have to authenticate by code
  UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(cnfHadoop) ;
  UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("user@REALM", "/some/path/to/user.keytab") ;
*/
  FileSystem fsCluster =FileSystem.get(cnfHadoop) ;
  Path source = new Path("/some/hdfs/path/to/XXX.har") ;
  Path target = new Path("/some/hdfs/path/to/XXX.har.gz") ;

  // alternative: "BZip2Codec" for better compression (but higher CPU cost)
  // alternative: "SnappyCodec" or "Lz4Codec" for lower compression (but much lower CPU cost)
  CompressionCodecFactory codecBootstrap = new CompressionCodecFactory(cnfHadoop) ;
  CompressionCodec codecHadoop =codecBootstrap.getCodecByClassName(GzipCodec.class.getName()) ;
  Compressor compressorHadoop =codecHadoop.createCompressor() ;

  byte[] buffer = new byte[16*1024*1024] ;
  int bufUsedCapacity ;
  InputStream  sourceStream =fsCluster.open(source) ;
  OutputStream targetStream =codecHadoop.createOutputStream(fsCluster.create(target, true), compressorHadoop) ;
  while ((bufUsedCapacity =sourceStream.read(buffer)) >0)
  { targetStream.write(buffer, 0, bufUsedCapacity) ; }
  targetStream.close() ;
  sourceStream.close() ;

..............
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Samson. Will give it a try and update.

Comment: So I gave it a try but it didn't work cause apparently `har` file is a directory and you can't compress a directory. Would you suggest creating a `tar` instead of a `har` (using `org.apache.commons.compress`) on HDFS and then gzipping it?

Comment: Duh... Looks like the HAR is a strange beast indeed. But if HDFS states that it is a directory, and lets you access individual files, then you should be able to build a single ZIP file from a HAR (using standard `java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream` and `. putNextEntry()` etc.) -- _disclaimer: I am not a big fan of the venerable TAR format_.

Comment: Ended up bzipping each file individually. -.-
 Thanks for the response, anyway. Very informative.