# How to zip multiple text files present on hdfs

Tags: linux, zip, hdfs, oozie, hue

Can anyone tell me that how can we zip multiple text files present on hdfs into one .zip file such that I can unzip it later into individual ones as per need .

I don't want to fetch files to local and then run zip command and putting back to hdfs because I will be using oozie for such action .

I don't want a big zip file having merged content . I just want utility or way like zip simple zip and unzip command in linux but files are on hdfs .

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You cannot Zip files "inside HDFS" -- you have to download the content on some node, Zip that content, and upload it back to HDFS. With Oozie, you can do that either with a Shell action and `hdfs dfs` commands *(but you will need some free space on local disks)* or with a Java action using custom code cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43517025/gzipping-har-files-on-hdfs-using-spark/43524848#43524848 *(and since data is streamed inside the JVM it doesn't use local disk)*

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for your response .!! I tried using shell action and used **zip** command functionality eg . zip foldername *.txt  but while through oozie it is giving me an error "zip" command not found because it is not recognize command in hadoop eg . `hdfs dfs copyToLocal sourcedir  destinationdir ; cd destinationdir ; zip foldername *.txt `

Comment: Maybe "zip" has not been installed on the worker nodes of your cluster -- check with your system admin *(for instance, we have to `sudo yum install zip unzip` every time we provision a new CentOS VM)*

Comment: You can use `tar -zcf blahblah.tgz *.txt` (i.e. Tar+GZip) as an alternative to `zip`